# How to write an app with repetitive parts?

Tags: android

I want to write an app with about 20 different Activity. Inside each activity there is some parts that are similar in some other activities. I divided each page to smart parts and write a separate layout for them. Then in activities I use `include` tag for adding that part to activity. 
I don't know what is the true way to implement this app. 
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Are you talking about layout or Java code?

Comment: Both of them. with using include tag i have to write repetitive code

Comment: have you tried using fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: No i didn't. Is there any limitation for number of fragments in an activity? and also does it effect on  app loading time?

Comment: i don't think there is any limitation. Loading time will depend on your code and layout structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `base activity` for similar methods and extend it in other activities.

And about `layouts` you can create similar layouts at first then include them to other layouts.

And for good structure i think use `MVP`.

Comment: Thank you, Is this method better than @Nabil suggestion?

Comment: Your welcome if you want to use fragment its another discussion , but in use fragments you can use baseFragment and include layouts and use MVP too.

Answer (score 2):

I have made sample BaseActivity. Make abstract method you want to use and just override to your class. You can use all Base Activity public method in your class. abstract method will override to your class and simple Public method will be optional if you want to use

```
public abstract class BaseMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initMethod();
        setContentView(getLayout());
        initUI();
        initListeners();
    }


    public abstract void initMethod();
    public abstract int getLayout();
    public abstract void initUI();
    public abstract void initListeners();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


    public String getEditString(CustomEdittext edittext){
        return edittext.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    public void getEditError(CustomEdittext edittext, String message){
        edittext.setError(message);
    }

    public static void showProgress(AppCompatActivity activity){
        try{
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
            progressDialog.show();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void hideProgress(){
        try{
            if(progressDialog!=null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void showToast(String message,Context context)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Hi this is sample that we can extend BaseActivity to our class.

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseMainActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    private Picasso picasso;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void initMethod() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }

    @Override
    public void initUI() {

        initToolbar();
        initDrawerLayout();
        initNavigationView();
    }
}
```